# Windows: Execute Batch File for a Custom Context Menu Item

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file, zip, contextmenu, unzip

I am looking to add a new item in a right click context menu for a certain file type. I suppose it would be easiest to run a batch file with the full path of the file as an argument. I need to rename the file, unzip it, then rezip it, then rename it. I suppose winzip command line would be appropriate tool to help with that, unless someone else has a suggestion.

My questions are:
- How can I add a custom context menu item based on file type
- How can I pass the file name as an argument to the batch file from the context menu
- Finally this may go out to 2-3 people, and it might be easier to simply have an installer that sets this up for them. Anyone know of any free installers that could do this?

Some details about why I am trying to do this:
I have a tool that is zipping things correctly, the program that is reading the zip files is not unzipping to standards it seems. It unzips in winzip legacy mode or something. Rather than fix a working program/investing time or attempt to do some ultra-fancy, crazy fix on a linux server for zipping into winzip legacy format a workaround seemed appropriate for now. These processes only really occur internally, but they are still painful/annoying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) is free, you might want to use that if you need to bundle the zip utility
- [Customizing a Shortcut Menu Using Static Verbs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144171%28VS.85%29.aspx#customize_verb_static)
- %1 in the command string in the registry is replaced with the filename
- [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/) or [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: NSIS is amazing. Between that article and the documentation I got the context menu working, and the only thing I had to do was use: http://download.cnet.com/Bat-To-Exe-Converter/3000-2069_4-10555897.html to compile the bat file to an EXE. I did need to use winzip though because I needed legacy mode or something. Thanks! :)